Migration from GoogleSignIn to Credential Manager. Get 'idToken' silently
I'm trying to migrate from GoogleSignIn to Credential Manager.
GoogleSignIn implementation
After authetication, I need to know idToken from time to time to make a request to our server
  val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(
    context,
    GoogleApiClientHelper.generateGoogleSignInOptions()
  )
  val silentSignIn = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn()
  if (!silentSignIn.isSuccessful || silentSignIn.result.isExpired) {
    throw IllegalStateException("Could not receive idToken")
  }

  val idToken = silentSignIn.result.idToken
  put("Authorization", "Bearer $idToken")

where GoogleApiClientHelper.generateGoogleSignInOptions() is:
fun generateGoogleSignInOptions(account: Account? = null): GoogleSignInOptions {

  val builder = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)

  builder.requestScopes(Scope(Constants.SCOPE_MAIL_GOOGLE_COM))
  builder.requestEmail()
  builder.requestIdToken(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
  account?.name?.let { builder.setAccountName(it) }

  return builder.build()
}

Credential Manager implementation
I would like to know how to handle the above situation with Credential Manager. Is it possible to get a valid idToken silently for the last authenticated user?
Please ask me if additional info is needed
I saw Authenticate users with Sign in with Google.
This code works well for me
val signInWithGoogleOption: GetSignInWithGoogleOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder()
  .setServerClientId(WEB_CLIENT_ID)
  .setNonce(<nonce string to use when generating a Google ID token>)
  .build()

fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
  // Handle the successfully returned credential.
  val credential = result.credential

  when (credential) {
    is CustomCredential -> {
      if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
        try {
          // Use googleIdTokenCredential and extract id to validate and
          // authenticate on your server.
          val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
            .createFrom(credential.data)
        } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
        }
      }
      else -> {
        // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
        Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
      }
    }

    else -> {
      // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
      Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected type of credential")
    }
  }
}

I can authenticate a user and get valid idToken after that(at this point). But I need to get a valid idToken for the last authenticated user later.

Hi Den. Let me make sure I understand your question before trying to answer that. Are you asking that the first time, you like user to see the "account selector" and then in the subsequent interactions, if user has already given the consent, you want that user to be signed in kind of silently and you get the ID Token with no user interaction?

Hi Ali. Thank you for your attention. You are right. In our app, during login, we use idToken to register/login and fetch the user configurations. After that, for example, once per hour we fetch the user configurations from our server to see if we have any updates. We use Bearer $idToken as Authorization value. It means we need to have a valid token for every request. GoogleSignIn helps us to do that without any user interaction(it looks like it refreshes idToken itself).

Den, there is no exact similar functionality for silenSignIn. The OneTap flow for sign-in (via CredMan) which shows a bottomsheet, has a somewhat similar functionality: if you have a single authorized account (i.e. an account that has previously given consent), then if you set the request parameters appropriately, it can sign the user back in without any user interactions and would give you an id-token. Is this something that you might be interested in exploring?

I've read almost all of your posts with android-credential-manager tag. Now I think I understand. Unfortunately, a user can have more than one authorized account on his device, so your case can not be used. I need to have idToken to use it in for example CoroutineWorker. Now I see it looks like Credential Manager can't provide and refresh idToken for the last used authorized account if there is more than one authorized. As you wrote in some posts, Credential Manager doesn't know which one should be returned. (Continued ...)

(Continued ...)  But based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/78258715/2451820 you write since you have more than one "qualified/authorized" credentials so the system doesn't know which one to pick to sign you in automatically. I don't understand why it's not possible to specify the account with which I want to interact? For example, GetGoogleIdOption.Builder().setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true).filter(accountId)

It is mostly because such a need is rare; callers of the authentication APIs usually don't attempt to do a silent refresh of the id-token, hence there is no accomodation for that. Another angle to look at this is the following: if there are, say, 2 authorized accounts, then you can interpret that as this user does use both accounts to sign into my app so next time that they open the app, it doesn't necessarily mean that they want to use the one they use last time, they may actually want to switch, so showing them both enables that scenario. Does that make sense?

It is mostly because such a need is rare; -> Got it. I thought maybe it was a security reason.

Does that make sense? -> Sorry, I didn't understand what you said. Could you clarify?

Let me add more details. Our app is an email client for Android. A user can add a few accounts to the app and switch between them. At the same time, ONLY one can work. After successful authentication, I use googleSignInClient.silentSignIn() to get a valid idToken when it is needed(for example get some user settings from our backend with "Authorization", "Bearer $idToken"). So the main point here is to get a valid idToken via Credential Manager(without the user interaction, no UI) as I do it via googleSignInClient.silentSignIn()
